# Read file line by line with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I wish to read several log files as they are written and process their input with asyncio. The code will have to run on windows. From what I understand from searching around both stackoverflow and the web, asynchronous file I/O is tricky on most operating systems (`select` will not work as intended, for example). While I'm sure I could do this with other methods (e.g. threads), I though I would try out asyncio to see what it is like. The most helpful answer would probably be one that describes what the "architecture" of a solution to this problem should look like, i.e. how different functions and coroutines should be called or scheduled.

The following gives me a generator that reads the files line by line (through polling, which is acceptable):

```
import time

def line_reader(f):
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(POLL_INTERVAL)
            continue
        process_line(line)
```

With several files to monitor and process, this sort of code would require threads. I have modified it slightly to be more usable with asyncio:

```
import asyncio

def line_reader(f):
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            yield from asyncio.sleep(POLL_INTERVAL)
            continue
        process_line(line)
```

This sort of works when I schedule it through the asyncio event loop, but if `process_data` blocks, then that is of course not good. When starting out, I imagined the solution would look something like

```
def process_data():
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        line = yield from line_reader()
        ...
```

but I could not figure out how to make that work (at least not without `process_data` managing quite a bit of state).

Any ideas on how I should structure this kind of code?

Comment: I have tested the topmost version of the code, and that is able to read changes to the file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> From what I understand from searching around both stackoverflow and the web, asynchronous file I/O is tricky on most operating systems (select will not work as intended, for example). While I'm sure I could do this with other methods (e.g. threads), I though I would try out asyncio to see what it is like.

`asyncio` *is* `select` based on *nix systems under the hood, so you won't be able to do non-blocking file I/O without the use of threads. On Windows, `asyncio` can use [IOCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which supports non-blocking file I/O, but this isn't supported by `asyncio`.

Your code is fine, except you should do blocking I/O calls in threads, so that you don't block the event loop if the I/O is slow. Fortunately, it's really simple to off load work to threads using the `loop.run_in_executor` function.

First, setup a dedicated thread-pool for your I/O:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
io_pool_exc = ThreadPoolExecutor()
```

And then simply offload any blocking I/O calls to the executor:

```
...
line = yield from loop.run_in_executor(io_pool_exc, f.readline)
...
```

Answer (score 46):

Using the [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles):

```
async with aiofiles.open('filename', mode='r') as f:
    async for line in f:
        print(line)
```

**EDIT 1**

As the @Jashandeep mentioned, you should care about blocking operations:

Another method is `select` and or `epoll`:

```
from select import select

files_to_read, files_to_write, exceptions = select([f1, f2], [f1, f2], [f1, f2], timeout=.1)
```

The `timeout` parameter is important here.

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select

**EDIT 2**

You can register a file for read/write with: [loop.add_reader()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.add_reader)

It uses internal EPOLL Handler inside the loop.

**EDIT 3**

But remember the Epoll will not work with regular files.

Answer (score 3):

Anyio has great support for asynchronouse file I/O. It even supports using the pathlib syntax. See: https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fileio.html

```
from anyio import open_file, run


async def main():
    async with await open_file('/some/path/somewhere') as f:
        async for line in f:
            print(line, end='')

run(main)
```

Answer (score -3):

`asyncio` doesn't support file operations yet, sorry.

Thus it cannot help with your problem.

Comment: Yes, but to be more constructive, I can approve the method: `loop.add_reader` (Sharing EPOLL handler inside the loop) is enough to read a file chunk by chunk without blocking the entire thread and achieve the maximum performance, So I disagree with you, Python supports reading files in asyncio manner with some limitations.

Comment: EPOLL doesn't support regular files on Linux